# DriveApp.getRootFolder() is returning null to webapp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

As part of a larger Google App Script webapp, I want to create a rudimentary file system with files/folders in the user's Google Drive.  I'm doing this through a  element where each  would be a different folder (prefixed with a '*') or file.

I have setup the webapp HTML to include the  element, but within this element I call a script that will populate the  via a call to google.script.run.withSuccessHandler.  It appears that this code runs as I'd expect, but the result of DriveApp.getRootFolder() is null, thereby making me unable to access the file structure.

```
// In the HTML file.
...
<head>
<script>
...
  // Populate options in the file/folder list based on the provided folder.
  function setFiles(folder)
  {
  alert(folder);
  return;
/*        // Get the select item.
    var e = document.getElementById("file-select");

    // First list all the folders at the top.
//@TODO Adding an asterick on folders to identify them for now, maybe have a different method later?
    var folderI = folder.getFolders();
    var i = 0;
    while(folderI.hasNext())
    {
      var fldr = folderI.next();
      e.innerHTML += "<option id='f_'" + i + "'>*" + fldr.getName() + "</option>";
      i++;
    }

    // Now list all the files in the current directory.
    i = 0;
    var fileI = folder.getFiles();
    while(fileI.hasNext())
    {
      var fle = fileI.next();
      e.inner.HTML += "<option id='f_'" + i + "'>*" + fle.getName() + "</option>";
      i++
    }
*/
....
</script>
</head>

<body>
...
<div id="select-files">
  <select id="file-select" size="10">
    <script>
      // Populate the initial file/folder list.
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(setFiles).getRootFolder();
    </script>
   </select>
</div>
...


// In code.gs
/**
 * Returns the root folder for the user.
 * @return The root folder of the user.
 */
function getRootFolder()
{
  return DriveApp.getRootFolder();
}
```

This is the code as I'm testing it now, hence my commenting out most of setFiles().  alert() results in 'null', but I'd expect it to be an 'Object [Object]' type that I could iterate through.

Interestingly, when I've added Logger.log() lines in the code.gs file, no log output is produced (I can't figure out why, because if I change the return value of getRootFolder() to a string, that string is displayed in the alert, so I know the code is entering that function correctly.

I'm wondering if this is a misunderstanding such that Google Drive (or maybe, generally, Google App Script specific objects) cannot be passed to an HTML file, though I couldn't find any clear documentation that this is the case.

Comment: I don't think Folder is a Javascript Object so it's probably an [illegal parameter](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values).

Comment: Try returning Folder properties like name, id, etc. using Javascript primitives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Cooper said in the comments, the [`Folder`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder) type is not [legal to send to the client](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values).  If you look at what a `Folder` contains, it is purely functions, which are not allowed to be sent over.

All that client-side you commented out in `setFiles` cannot function in the user's browser.  Even if you were able to pass the `Folder` code into the client, what would `folder.getFolders()` mean to the user's browser?  It would start looking for the rest of the code from `DriveApp`, which doesn't exist in the browser, and still fail.

> I'm wondering if this is a misunderstanding such that Google Drive (or maybe, generally, Google App Script specific objects) cannot be passed to an HTML file

[What you get passed to the HTML file is documented here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/).  [Pay special attention to how `google.script.run` works](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run).

No, you cannot pass the entire environment of your server-side code to the client (e.g. pass all of `DriveApp` and its dependences over to the client).

What you can do on both sides is construct your own version of `Folder` which exports the strings on the server side and reconstructs them on the client side.  Note that arrays of strings are OK, so I would put things like the child, parent folder names and IDs in arrays.  Just to be safe, I use JSON stringify/parse to strip functions out.  This example works without the JSON part, but on more complicated objects it can be nice to clean them up.

client-side code

```js
// just to log that it works
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(response => {
  response = JSON.parse(response);
  console.log({response})
}).getFolder();
```

Code.gs

```js
// client-code calls this to get folder info
function getFolder(id) {
  return JSON.stringify(new Folder_(id ? DriveApp.getFolderById(id) : DriveApp.getRootFolder()));
}
// constructor for a `folder` suitable to send to the client
function Folder_(folder) {
  this.id = folder.getId();
  this.name = folder.getName();
  this.foldersIds = [];
  this.foldersNames = [];
  this.parentsIds = [];
  this.parentsNames = [];
  this._extractFolders(folder, "folders");
  this._extractFolders(folder, "parents");
}
// one function for both "getFolders" and "getParents"
Folder_.prototype._extractFolders = function(folder, type) {
  var folders = folder["get" + type.replace(/^./, function(str){return str.toUpperCase()})]();
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    this[type + "Ids"].push(folder.getId());
    this[type + "Names"].push(folder.getName());
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks so much dwmorrin and Cooper. This is extraordinarily helpful (and the links/code examples make complete sense).